# Mac not re-waking networked PC

Tags: network, wake-on-lan

I have a simple home network with 2 Macs, a Windows 7 PC, and an OpenELEC PC.

I sometimes watch media using VLC from the [OpenELEC machine](http://openelec.tv). It is set in such a way that it goes to sleep when possible which is perfect and as it should be.

When I turn on my Windows 7 PC, I browse the network and select the OpenELEC box. It tells me it can't connect, but after 5 or so seconds it starts working. This is because it has woken up and started being available on the network.

When I connect to an already-woken OpenELEC box from my Mac (one Mavericks / one El Cap) it connects right away and can start working with files on the network.

But if the OpenELEC machine goes to sleep **even if** the Mac is busy using its files, it stays asleep. I've had VLC die horribly because the underlying network suddenly isn't there anymore.

No amount of mucking about on the Mac seems to be able to get it to **wake** from a Mac. Windows > Linux will do it; Linux > Linux will do it; Mac > Linux won't do a thing.

How do I get a Mac to tell a remote network machine that has an **active data stream** not to go to sleep in the middle of using it?

Comment: Have you tried asking on the [OpenELEC forum](http://openelec.tv/forum)? Ask Different is the best place for your Apple questions but I suspect few here can help with OpenELEC specific problems.

Comment: The problem is the Mac won't wake network devices. It won't wake my Windows 7 PC (which has WOL set properly and wakes from other devices).

Comment: What are you using to send the WOL packet from your Mac? Have you tried [wakeonlan](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-os-x-wake-on-lancommand-line-utility/)?

Comment: You seem to be implying is that Mac's, unlike most other operating systems, don't just send a wake on lan packet by default requesting network access? How would I do this *during* existing network access? I'll give the perl file a go in the interim